# split huge docker-compose file contains fragment into multiiple

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have huge docker-compose file containing fragments and anchors like this:

```yaml
version: '3'

x-common-repo-volumes:
 - &source-bin /path/lib/:/work/lib/
 - ...
 - ...

services:    
  foobar:
    image: ...
    volumes:
      - *source-bin
      - ...
      - ...
```

I want to split all fragments to separate file named `comon.yml` :

```
version: '3'

x-common-repo-volumes:
 - &source-bin /path/lib/:/work/lib/
 - ...
 - ...
```

and real services into `main.yml` (there are also more yml files that shares the same fragments like `second.yml`)

```
services:    
  foobar:
    image: ...
    volumes:
      - *source-bin
      - ...
      - ...
```

When I try to run this two file with `docker compose -f` like this:

`docker compose -f common.yml -f main.yml up d`

I get this error:

`unknown anchor 'source-bin' referenced`

what is wrong here and How can I split huge docker-compose file containing so many anchors and fragments to multiple ones so I can import the shared fragments into all of splitted services files?

NOTE: I've already found similar issue on [github](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5621) not sure using pipe (`|`) is good idea or not here

Comment: How many volumes do you have?  Why?  In normal use I might expect one or two containers to have a volume mount (your database, but not your application containers), and then only one volume on each (for its storage directory).

Comment: there are almost 30 volumes. most of them shared (almost 10) that I need then in all services

Answer (score 0):

I was investigating this interesting question and it seems unfortunately it is not possible to make anchor references between different compose files.
[I attach a link](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/10912) where they apparently confirm that it is not possible.

P.S: There is a possible solution that user @Aradiv shared in a github issue, but I honestly don't know if it will work for your case, [I'll leave the link anyway](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5621).